# Adding timezone in datetime

Tags: jquery, date, freemarker

Following is my Freemarker code, which I am using to parse the dates and display it in friendly dates, like 1h ago, yesterday, last month etc. It is working fine, but when I compared the output with the actual results, it was parsing the results wrongly, i.e. the time "2014-06-19T22:07:33+00:00" should actually show **11h ago**, but it is showing **2h ago**, I think the issue is with the third line below in the code, where I need to pass the timezone as well, can you please help me in how to do that, I tried +ZZ:ZZ in the end, but it didn't work.

```
<#include "relativeTime.ftl" />

<#assign time = "2014-06-19T22:07:33+00:00">
<#assign postTimeObject = time?datetime("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss") /> //I think I need to pass the timezone, how?
<#assign postTimeString = relativeTime(postTimeObject) />

${postTimeString}
```

Prints: **2h ago**

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker uses Java's standard date formatter (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), so the pattern you want is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssX"`.

(BTW, the approach of that template is a bit suspicious. Can't you just use `Date` objects, instead of converting `String`-s to `Date`-s?)